# Finding the determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix of rational functions

Tags: matrices, determinant

Here is my matrix. How do I find the determinant of this one?

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\ \dfrac{z^{2}+1}{z}& \dfrac{z^{4}+1}{z^2}& \dfrac{z^{6}+1}{z^3}& \ldots & \dfrac{z^{2n}+1}{z^n}\\ \dfrac{z^{4}+1}{z^2}& \dfrac{z^{8}+1}{z^4}& \dfrac{z^{12}+1}{z^6}&  \ldots &\dfrac{z^{4n}+1}{z^{2n}}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\ \dfrac{z^{2(n-1)}+1}{z^{n-1}}& \dfrac{z^{4(n-1)}+1}{z^{2(n-1)}} & \dfrac{z^{6(n-1)}+1}{z^{3(n-1)}}& \ldots & \dfrac{z^{2n(n-1)}+1}{z^{n(n-1)}}&\end{pmatrix} $$

I'm really trying to solve it but I can't think of anything. Does it have anything to do with Vandermonde?

Comment: Note that entry $(i,j)$ is $$z^{(i-1) j} + z^{-(i-1) j}$$

Comment: Take a look at the Discrete Fourier Transform matrix.

Comment: I took a look at the Discrete Fourier Transform matrix and still I have no idea how to solve it. May you help me?

Comment: I assume $z \in \Bbb C$. Evaluate on the unit circle of $\Bbb C$. Do you see what I am getting at?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest, we can reformulate this determinant ($D$) as the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix. Until I saw this question I had never even heard of a Vandermonde matrix, so there are probably easier ways of handling this.

First we note that the elements of the matrix can be written as
$$p_k=z^k+z^{-k}$$

Then
$$ D=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\ p_1&p_2 & p_3 & \ldots & p_n\\ p_2 & p_4 & p_6 &  \ldots &p_{2n}\\ p_3 & p_6 & p_9 &  \ldots &p_{3n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\ p_r & p_{2r} & p_{3r} &  \ldots &p_{rn}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\ p_{n-1} &  p_{2(n-1)}  &  p_{3(n-1)}  & \ldots &   p_{n(n-1)} &\end{vmatrix} $$

This looks a bit more like a Vandermonde determinant except that (a) it is transposed from the way the Wikipedia page lays it out; and (b) we want things like $p^k$ rather than $p_k$.

(a) is irrelevant because taking the transpose of a matrix doesn't affect its determinant.
(b) can be addressed with some row manipulations.
We note that
$$p_r^2 = (z^r+z^{-r})^2=p_{2r}+2 $$
$$p_r^3 = (z^r+z^{-r})^3=p_{3r}+3p_r $$
$$p_r^4 = (z^r+z^{-r})^4=p_{4r}+4p_{2r}+6 $$
$$p_r^5 = (z^r+z^{-r})^5=p_{5r}+5p_{3r}+10p_{r} $$

and in general

$$p_r^k = p_{kr} + a_{k-2}p_{(k-2)r} + a_{k-4}p_{(k-4)r}+\cdots $$
for some constants $a$. So we can change $p_{kr}$ to $p_r^k$ with the only changes being combinations of the previous rows.

For example we can rewrite the third row ($p_2,p_4,p_6,\dots$) as ($p_1^2,p_2^2,p_3^2\dots$) by subtracting twice the first row from it. Similarly we can rewrite the fourth row ($p_3,p_6,p_9,\dots$) as ($p_1^3,p_2^3,p_3^3\dots$) by subtracting three times the second row from it. In general, we can rewrite all of the rows and get:
$$ D=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\ p_1&p_2 & p_3 & \ldots & p_n\\ p_1^2 & p_2^2 & p_3^2 &  \ldots &p_{n}^2\\ p_1^3 & p_2^3 & p_3^3 &  \ldots &p_{n}^3\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\ p_1^r & p_{2}^r & p_{3}^r &  \ldots &p_{n}^r\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\ p_1^{n-1} &  p_2^{n-1}  &  p_3^{n-1}  & \ldots &   p_n^{n-1} &\end{vmatrix} $$

This is exactly a Vandermonde determinant and so, as shown on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix
, we have
$$D= \prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} (p_j - p_i)$$

It is helpful to write
$$q_k=z^k-z^{-k}$$
Which leads to
$$p_j-p_i=q_{\frac12(j+i)}q_{\frac12(j-i)}$$
and so
$$D= \prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} q_{\frac12 (j+i)} q_{\frac12 (j-i)} $$

Writing $r_k=q_{\frac12 k}$ gives the slightly simpler looking
$$D= \prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} r_{j+i} \,  r_{j-i} $$
$$= \prod_{j=2}^n \prod_{i=1}^{j-1}  r_{j+i} \, r_{j-i} $$
$$= \prod_{j=2}^n \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{2j-1}  r_{k} }{r_j} $$
$$=   \frac{r_1 \, r_3}{r_2}  \frac{r_1 \, r_3 \, r_5}{r_3}\cdots  \frac{r_1 \, r_3 \, r_5 \dots r_{2n-1}}{r_n}  $$
$$= \frac{r_1^n \, r_3^{n-1} \,  r_5^{n-2} \dots r_{2n-1}^{1} }{r_1 \, r_2\,  r_3\dots r_n}   $$
$$=  \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}  r_{2k-1}^{n+1-k} }{\prod_{k=1}^{n}  r_{k} } $$

where
$$r_k=z^{\frac12 k}-z^{-\frac12 k}$$